# .NET SCTP implementation

Tags: .net, sockets, sctp

I'm looking for a .NET implementation of the [SCTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol) protocol.
A component or a C#/F# source code would be preferred, however if no such thing is available a VB.NET source code could probably work too.
The project I'm working on is targeting the .NET Framework v3.5 but anything that works with .NET v2 to v4 is welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A .NET 4 assembly now gets installed with version 1.1.6 of [SctpDrv](http://www.bluestop.org/SctpDrv/); it provides an API that's similar to the Socket class but with new methods for SCTP.

Comment: is it self-contained assembly or just binding to kernel driver?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [SctpDrv](http://www.bluestop.org/SctpDrv/).

From the link

"SctpDrv is provided as a kernel driver which contains the SCTP stack. A Winsock provider dll is registered with Windows and gets called whenever an application wants to send data over SCTP. This way, the functionality is provided transparently to applications: IPPROTO_SCTP is just another protocol available in the socket (WSASocket) function call. The SCTP specific functions such as sctp_send are provided by linking to sctpsp.lib. "

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately drivers are not a feasible solution in the context of the project I'm working on.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this helps you, but an alternative with some similar features to SCTP is the [Lidgren Network](http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network/) library (C#, user-space component, custom protocol based on UDP).

Comment: I'm not really in love with the poor amount of information available and the fact that it's going one more layer up, however had I found this earlier it'd have meant saving many resources. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find anything in C# but there are some implementations in C++ and Java on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/search/?words=SCTP&type_of_search=soft&pmode=0&inex=1&sortselect=trove__160&registration_date__0=&trove__225=456&trove__274=369&trove__160=165&trove__199=426&trove__13=14&trove__1=534&trove__6=7&trove__496=499&newfilter=Apply).

Comment: Unfortunately those are not viable solutions for me. Given the project I can't even consider using IKVM + Java. +1 For the effort

Comment: Any luck with this emaster70? I'd love to see code on how one accomplishes this.

Comment: No luck at all. Had to give up on using SCTP because in my case the cost of implementing it internally exceeded the benefits that could be obtained for using it.

Comment: I have a .NET wrapper that I'm making good progress on, that will be added to SctpDrv. I expect it to be available in the next couple of months.